# The multi-part identifier \"blah@blah.co.uk\" could not be bound. when using SqlCommand c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-update, console-application

I'm trying to build a simple deployment helper for our deployment process and I'm trying to do an update on a SQL database in azure from a small .NET console application.

The method thats throwing the issue is right below

```cs
        private static void ConnectToSqlDatabase(string azureDatabaseUrl, IConfiguration config, string authUserEmail)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                connBuilder.DataSource = azureDatabaseUrl;
                connBuilder.UserID = config["SqlDatabase:ZupaKeyReleaseUserName"];
                connBuilder.Password = config["SqlDatabase:ZupaKeyReleasePassword"];
                connBuilder.InitialCatalog = "zupaauthentication";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = $"UPDATE AspNetUsers SET EmailConfirmed = 1 WHERE Email = {authUserEmail}";

                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

We are using identity server 4 which has a whole bunch of tables that need updating for a verity of custom-defined reasons. When trying to do the insert below with a valid email address I get the exception:

> The multi-part identifier \"chris.marshall@zupa.co.uk\" could not be bound.

```cs
command.CommandText = $"UPDATE AspNetUsers SET EmailConfirmed = 1 WHERE Email = {authUserEmail}";
```

UPDATE: Was also wondering how multiline SQL commands would be entered as that's not working either. For example this sort of statement

```sql
INSERT INTO AspNetUserRoles (UserId,RoleId)
SELECT        anu.Id
        ,    r.Id 
FROM    AspNetUsers anu
CROSS JOIN 
(
        SELECT Id 
        FROM AspNetRoles 
        WHERE [Name] = @targetrole
) r
WHERE    Email = @targetuser
```

My guess was to single line it and use the .add to add the values but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You should be using parameters for your queries, you can find an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Im what you are saying is this? 

```c#
command.CommandText = $"UPDATE AspNetUsers SET EmailConfirmed = 1 WHERE Email = @Email";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", authUserEmail);
```

Comment: Almost, however I believe parameters may be case sensitive, so I'd make sure those align, also avoid using `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - and that link shows how to do that properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means some column you are using isn't found, SQL syntax error.  pseudo code below, something like that... (you are missing apostrophes around email value)

Use the `@` sign to make it a parameter. After that add parameter to query. You are missing some characters, so it thinks your email is an actual column. Just update your query.

```
command.commandtext = "update aspnetusers set emailconfirmed = 1 where email = @email"
command.parameters.add("@email", authUserEmail)
```

Comment: Thanks David, I updated it.  This stuff brings back memories.

Comment: Adding to this answer using command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = authUserEmail; feels better as its giving it more of a definition